# Given a csv file in the format "MANAGER, DEPARTMENT", Write a method that given a manager name, returns their department

Tags: java

So I have a csv file in the format "MANAGER, DEPARTMENT"
How to write an efficient method that given a manager name, returns their department (preferably in java)

This is what I have in python:

```
with open('file.csv', 'rt') as f:
 reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
 for row in reader:
      if manager == "specified manager": 
          print row
```

this prints both manager and department...what I want is just the department and this method has o(n) which is not that efficient.

Comment: Show us code you've attempted.

Comment: Don't worry about efficiency yet. Just write any way you can. If you can't, then ask help from your teacher.

Comment: is there algorithm can improve the time complexity? o(n) is not efficient

Answer (score 0):

Read the whole file into a map once and serve lookups from there. This gives O(1) for the lookup and O(n) for init.

Comment: What language is that supposed to be? And no, _never_ use simple splitting to parse a CSV file. CSV Parsers exist for a reason.

Comment: Well, then it's the most ugly and incomprehensible pseudo code I've ever seen. Looks like pseudo-cobol or something similar. Not that it's useful in any way - basically, all you're saying is "use a map".

Comment: Note that _correct_ doesn't correlate with _useful_, and especially not with the goal of SO to curate content useful to a broader audience of programmers and not just OP...